# fgets() crashing C program when used more than once

Tags: c, crash, fgets

I have an array declared and populated with 3 strings (Math, Physics, English). I used the fgets() to get new subject to add to the array, and this is working fine. However, whenever I copy the same chunk of code to get another subject from the user, the program crashes.

Why is this happening? How do I get strings from user and add it to the array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *subjectName[1000];
    int numOfSubj = 0;
    int numOfUserAddedSubj = 0;

    subjectName[numOfSubj] = "Math";
    numOfSubj++;
    subjectName[numOfSubj] = "Physics";
    numOfSubj++;
    subjectName[numOfSubj] = "English";
    numOfSubj++;

//int k;
//for(k=0; k<1; k++)
//{
    // add user
    printf("Enter new subject name: ");
    fgets(subjectName[numOfSubj], 50, stdin);
    numOfUserAddedSubj++;
    numOfSubj++;
//}


// add another user
/*printf("Enter new subject name: ");
fgets(subjectName[numOfSubj], 50, stdin);
numOfUserAddedSubj++;
numOfSubj++;*/



// display content of array
int i;
for(i=0; i < ((strlen(subjectName))+numOfUserAddedSubj); i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", subjectName[i]);
}


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `subjectName[numOfSubj]` that is an uninitialised `char *` variable. That is, you are trying to write to an invalid address. Either dynamically allocate memory for each `char` buffer (e.g. `subjectName[numOfSubj] = malloc(50)`) or declare it statically as `subjectName[1000][50]`.

Comment: You are passing an uninitialised pointer to `fgets`, which uses it differently from your earlier assignments of pointers to string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working in first case because you are initialising the char array with subject name so compiler allocating memory.

In USER case you need to allocate memory before taking input from user.

> fgets(subjectName[numOfSubj], 50, stdin); //Here you passed null char
>   array

so to avoid error do

```
subjectName[numOfSubj] = malloc( 50 ); //memory allocation

 fgets(subjectName[numOfSubj], 50, stdin);
```

and `free` the memory (Which is allocated by malloc) whenever you finish the use of it  .

```
free(subjectName[numOfSubj] );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Got it working now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `subjectName` is array of type `char*`.
Your first 3 strings defined statically.
For the string you want to get via `fgets()` you need to allocate memory using `mallaoc` first and only then call `fgets()`.

Something like:

```
subjectName[numOfSubj] = (char *) malloc(50*sizeof(char));
fgets(subjectName[numOfSubj], 50, stdin);
```

Don't forget to `free` the allocated memory at the end.
Please note that you may want to consider different approaches. You may statically define the array: `char subjectName[1000][50]` and use `strcpy()` to populate it with "Math", "Physics" and "English".

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of 1000 pointers, but the pointers that are relevant to this problem don't point to anything. You need to `malloc` some memory for the pointers before calling `fgets`, e.g.

```
printf("Enter new subject name: ");
subjectName[numOfSubj] = malloc( 50 );
fgets(subjectName[numOfSubj], 50, stdin);
```

Comment: Not quite correct, here the first 3 pointers point to string literals.

Comment: @MichaelWalz The question was, "How do I get strings from user and add it to the array?"

Comment: Yes, but in the question the 1st 3 pointers don't point to nothing, they do point to string literals.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks for focusing on the irrelevant. I have updated my answer.